# How can I calculate the number of minutes per day between a daterange

Tags: ssms, date-range

First off I apologize I do not even know where to start and haven't been able to find anything specific to this particular question.

I have a table with datetimes (start and end) and i need to find a way to get minutes/hours between those days.  It could either be a sum of the time on weekdays or a some kind of pivot on each day and grouping by the ID number.  I had thought to assign a value to the number of days however the times are random and do not start/end at midnight so I am at a loss as how to approach this.

Here are some examples of the date/time format if that helps.

startdate 2018-12-14 10:53:01
enddate 2018-12-27 11:50:00

Any helps or hints would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

forgot to include I am working in SQL Server (SSMS)

**Editing For Additional Clarification**

Here is a sample date range with an ID number, I wanted to keep it simple.

|ID number|   start time   |end time

|1        |12/14/2018 10:53|12/17/2018 12:00

here is what I'm trying to achieve (the separation of each date range/ID #)

ID number|    start time    |end time        |mins|

1        |  12/14/2018 10:53|12/14/2018 23:59|786 |

1        |  12/15/2018 0:00 |12/15/2018 23:59|1439|

1        |  12/16/2018 0:00 |12/16/2018 23:59|1439|

1        |  12/17/2018 0:00 |12/17/2018 12:00|960 |

Comment: what language are you working in? that will likely influence the approach taken to solve this problem

Comment: As @DacreDenny pointed, include the technologies you are using, code (if applicable) and attempted solutions (if applicable).

Comment: sorry forgot to include that, using SQL Server (SSMS)

Comment: @JosephClapham consider updating your question by adding those details. Also add the appropriate tags to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The `MINUTE` parameter of the `DATEDIFF` function can be used to determine the difference in minutes between two datetime columns.  As below, the second parameter is the start date and the third parameter is the end date, with the result being the amount of time in the specified interval (days, minutes, etc.) from the start to the end date.  If you need to find the number of hours between these two columns the `HOUR` parameter can be used for this.  Grouping can be performed as well, as in the second example.

**DATEDIFF:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateColumn, EndDateColumn)
```

**DATEDIFF with Grouping and Aggregation:**

```
SELECT ColumnA, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateColumn, EndDateColumn)) as DifferenceInMinutes
FROM YourSchema.YourTable
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

Comment: I will clarify my original question a little more as it is a little more involved and include a sample of a results set.